# Error while using Sitecore Fake DB with Sitecore 8.2

Tags: fakedb

I am getting an error as:

> Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=1.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

While accessing Sitecore FakeDB in my MSTEST unit testing project.

- Sitecore Version : 8.2 update 2
- Sitecore FakeDB: 1.7.4
- .Net Framework: 4.5.2

What can be the issue here?

Comment: can you check the version of Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection dll in your website?

Comment: In my Sitecore application it is 1.0.0.20622.

Comment: Not sure how you are referencing the dll (nuget package or dll reference) in your Test project, but you can take a look at what version it is set in the Project/References.

Comment: I have DLL reference of Sitecore.Kernel.dll v8.2 update 2 same dll i have referred in Unit testing project whereas I have referred nuget package of Sitecore Fake DB v 1.7.4. With higher version of fakedb dll is not getting resolved as i have dot net framework 4.5.2

Comment: Can you try to add a reference in your Test project to the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection dll or use the nuget package?

Comment: What have you tried? What have you done to debug this yourself? This question needs a lot more information to be able to answer this.

Comment: Thanks for the Response.

I have reinstalled Sitecore using nuget package. I have verified steps provided Jean-Nicolas G. response.

It did worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that your Test project has at least the following references:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Lucene.Net" version="3.0.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Sitecore.FakeDb" version="1.7.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Sitecore.Kernel.NoReferences" version="8.2.161221" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Sitecore.Logging.NoReferences" version="8.2.161221" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Sitecore.Nexus.NoReferences" version="8.2.161221" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
</packages>
```

You only need to add two nuget packages in your solution with the dependencies: `Sitecore.Nexus` and `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`.

Answer (score 1):

I remember having some issues with error messages not corresponding to the actual issue. If you can make sure of all of these (assuming you are following Helix principles here):

Declare databases configuration on each projects
(***ex : Feature/YourFeautre/App_Config/Include/Feature/Sitecore.license.config***)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <databases>
      <database id="core">
        <patch:attribute name="type">Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel</patch:attribute>
      </database>
      <database id="master">
        <patch:attribute name="type">Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel</patch:attribute>
      </database>
      <database id="web">
        <patch:attribute name="type">Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel</patch:attribute>
      </database>
    </databases>
    <!-- EVENTING -->
    <eventing defaultProvider="sitecore">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Eventing.EventProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" systemDatabaseName="core" />
      </providers>
    </eventing>
  </sitecore>
```

Declare the license configuration on each projects.(***ex : Feature/YourFeautre/App_Config/Include/Feature/Sitecore.license.config***)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="LicenseFile" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\yourInstance\App_Data\license.xml" />
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Then in your tests, you should be using these :

```
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.FakeDb;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation;
using Xunit;
```

In your projects references, you should have those :
[image]

[Official doc](https://github.com/sshushliapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/wiki/Installation) said you need those :

```
Lucene.Net.dll
Sitecore.Analytics.dll
Sitecore.Kernel.dll
Sitecore.Logging.dll
Sitecore.Nexus.dll
```

But I make it work without ***Sitecore.Analytics.dll*** and ***Sitecore.Logging.dll***

After it is all said and done, make sure you are using compatible versions within your projects. I think your ***Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection*** is good, would also make sure to have ***Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions*** in your references. So within your packages.config it should look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <!-- [...your other packages...] -->
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

I would also recommend to take a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39802162/what-is-the-minimum-nugets-footprint-for-sitecore-fakedb-tests/39802163 because it feels like, in your similar case, you would end up using this fakedb version :

```
 <package id="Sitecore.FakeDb" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net452" />
```

and also include sitecore.logging

```
<package id="Sitecore.Logging.NoReferences" version="8.2.160729" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Response.

I have reinstalled Sitecore using nuget package.
I have verified steps provided Jean-Nicolas G. response.

It did worked.